# Add number to a float value which has a comma as the decimal character

Tags: php, loops, sum

i want to SUM number using loop in php. And here's my code

```
$point = 0,3;

for ($i=1;$i<=40;$i++){
 $total = $point + $i;
}

echo $total;
```

But when I run the program, it print wrong result. It printed 40.3, and the right result is 12

The point is, I want to SUM each point until 40 times.
example : 0.3+0.3+0.3+...+0.3 (40 times)

Comment: `$total += $point;` you are wrongly adding the counter on each loop in your code.

Comment: I'll be that person that asks why a loop if you can do: `40 * $point`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this

```
$point = 0.3;    
$total = 0;
for ($i=1;$i<=40;$i++){
    $total = $total+$point;
}
```